# Image button inside a Data table

Tags: datatable

I'm facing a scenario that i need to add image button inside a datatable. Is it possible to add an image button control inside a datatable.

I'm using Framework 3.5 and C# language.

Thanks In Advance!

Regards,
Ranga

Comment: which language? please retag.

Comment: We'll need more info. What language, framework etc.?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are trying to work with a user interface control like a DataGrid or DataGridView. DataTable is an ADO.NET class for holding data from a database. It doesn't present data in a user interface, so adding an image button maes no sense.

I presume you're working with a grid of some sort, but in order to get a sensible answer you need to tell us which one. Is your user interface WPF, Windows Forms, or ASP.NET? Specifically, which grid class are you trying to use?